# EF Core aggregation query

Tags: entity-framework-core

I use EF Core 5 and this query throws an exception. Id and EntityId are uniqueidentifiers in both tables.

query:

```
            var records = await (from r in _dbContext.Set<MedicalRecord>()
                          join d in _dbContext.Set<Document>()
                               on r.Id equals d.EntityId into grouping
                          select new { r, DocumentCount = grouping.Count() }).ToListAsync();
```

here is an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<MedicalRecord>()
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: DbSet<Document>(), 
        outerKeySelector: r => r.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: d => d.EntityId, 
        resultSelector: (r, grouping) => new { 
            r = r, 
            DocumentCount = grouping
                .AsQueryable()
                .Count()
         })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

Thank you

Comment: `GroupJoin` is not a grouping query. Do you really need whole `MedicalRecord`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv That's interesting. No, I can map the MedicalRecord later. How do I create a SQL query that will join two tables and group it?

Comment: By grouping you can return only fields which are grouping keys. So ensure which fields are needed and make group by by these fields. If you have original SQL I can help here to translate to the LINQ.

Comment: This is a result of their (EF Core team) unwilling to translate `GroupJoin`. Use collection navigation property if you have one (as you should) or correlated `SelectMany` + `Count` (or just `Count` with correlated predicate).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv `GroupJoin` is not like `GroupBy`. Please don't put them in the same box as EF Core team. And what exact SQL query are you expecting here to "help out"? The LINQ query with proper navugation property is simple as `_dbContext.Set<MedicalRecord>().Select(r => new { r, Count = r.Documents.Count() }`